# Multiply horizontal times vertical vectors of matrices and sum the result without loop

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, octave

Basically, I have 2 matrices and I want to rewrite this:

```
for i = 1:m
  result += A(:, i) * B(:, i)';
end
```

Without using for loop and I have no idea how to approach that. I've been strugling to solve it for several hours so I ask you guys to help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no different than simply doing [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) of `A` and the transpose of `B`.

```
result = A * B.';
```

Just for completeness...

```
m = 10;
A = rand(15, m);
B = rand(12, m);

result = zeros(size(A, 1), size(B, 1));
for k = 1:m
    result = result + A(:,k) * B(:,k).';
end

difference = max(max(abs(result - A *B.')));

difference = 

    8.8818e-16
```

Comment: I am so embarrassed. Thank you so much.